# How to remotely control a CentOS 5.4 install

Tags: centos, system-installation, remote

I need to support a legacy system that's running CentOS 5.4. There are errors coming up during the install and walking through the admin on the other end is quite tedious and inefficient.

Does anyone know if there's a way where I can take over the install session remotely somehow with vnc/teamviewer or ssh?

The method chosen will need to support some sort of authentication as well. I don't mind doing the installation in text mode either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CentOS's installer, Anaconda, supports a couple of different installation methods that you can use to help your remote administrator. Quoting from [the project's web page](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda):

> Installation can be scripted with [kickstart](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Kickstart) to provide a fully unattended installation that can be duplicated on scores of machines. It can also be run over VNC on headless machines.

Andrew Okhmat wrote [an article](http://supportex.net/2011/06/install-centos-fedora-remotely/) that describes the VNC method.

The kickstart method may also be helpful, as it would let you build up a working installation recipe on a local system, then ship the kickstart file to the remote site to try.

Comment: Problem with kickstart is - that if you encounter an error there VNC is not started. So you have to have remote console access (e.g. by RAC/iLo ...)